# wget download pdf files fail

Tags: linux, pdf, wget

I am using:

```
wget -r -A pdf https://labraj.uni-mb.si
```

but instead of pdf's I get this output in console:

```
--2013-03-23 15:11:03--  https://labraj.uni-mb.si/
Resolving labraj.uni-mb.si (labraj.uni-mb.si)... 164.8.230.26
Connecting to labraj.uni-mb.si (labraj.uni-mb.si)|164.8.230.26|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://labraj.uni-mb.si/Splo%C5%A1ne_informacije [following]
--2013-03-23 15:11:09--  https://labraj.uni-mb.si/Splo%C5%A1ne_informacije
Reusing existing connection to labraj.uni-mb.si:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
labraj.uni-mb.si: Permission deniedlabraj.uni-mb.si/index.html: No such file or directory

Cannot write to `labraj.uni-mb.si/index.html' (Success).
```

How can I do this properly?

Comment: Can you run `mkdir labraj.uni-mb.si` and see what happens? Then, try the same `wget command` again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example, but I do not think that it will grab from subfolders.

From http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/the-ultimate-wget-download-guide-with-15-awesome-examples/

> ```
> 14. Download Only Certain File Types Using wget -r -A
> ```
>
> You can use this under following situations:
>
> Download all images from a website Download all videos from a website
>   Download all PDF files from a website
>
> ```
> $ wget -r -A.pdf http://url-to-webpage-with-pdfs/
> ```

You may also need to change the browser agent so your `wget` does not appear as a spider.

Comment: This is the same as I posted above. If I leave out the `-A.pdf` part it works otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: What is an example URL of a PDF file located on this site?

Comment: The OP is right, this command _should_ work but doesn't. I also tried what was suggested [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27247/22222) but no luck. It works for non pdf files (`.png`, for example) but fails specifically for PDFs.